# Syntax error when trying to parse arguments Python shell

Tags: python, shell, syntax-error, argparse, args

I have some code that I am trying to run in a Python shell (IDLE) but there seems to be a problem with the way I am parsing arguments in the Python shell.

Here is the code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage.segmentation import mark_boundaries
from skimage.util import img_as_float
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the image and convert it to a floating point data type
image = img_as_float(io.imread(args["image"]))

# loop over the number of segments
for numSegments in (100, 200, 300):
    # apply SLIC and extract (approximately) the supplied number
    # of segments
    segments = slic(image, n_segments = numSegments, sigma = 5)

    # show the output of SLIC
    fig = plt.figure("Superpixels -- %d segments" % (numSegments))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.imshow(mark_boundaries(image, segments))
    plt.axis("off")

# show the plots
plt.show()
```

When I try to run the program with the line `Slic.py --image 0021.jpg` I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Not sure what I am doing wrong, probably really obvious to some but any help is greatly appreciated.

The code was found at the link below under the SLIC example at the bottom of the page, he even shows how to run the code but it doesn't work for me:

www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/28/a-slic-superpixel-tutorial-using-python

Comment: Does it tell you where the error is? What version of python are you using?

Comment: @EtanReisner im using Python 2.7.5 and the error doesn't seem to be on anything specific, as when I try using a .jgp file it says that the 'j' is invalid syntax and when I use a .png file it says that the '.' (full stop) is where the error is.

Comment: @EtanReisner just to be clear the invalid syntax doesn't seem to be in the actual code, but instead in the arguments that I am trying to parse.

Comment: what happens if you pass the argument in "quotes"?

Comment: @Kells1986 If I parse it in quotes it returns the same line 'python slic.py --image 0021.jpg' with no errors, but doesn't seem to actually run the program.

Comment: Shell quoting is not the issue. I *think* the issue here might be that the default type of an argument in argparse is an integer and you need to tell it to expect a string (or that it sees the digits and assumes an integer and then blows up on the non-digit input). The documentation seems to indicate otherwise though. But try adding `type=file` or `type=str` to the `add_argument` call?

Comment: @EtanReisner Tried both but still get the same error.

Comment: Wild guess: maybe the code was only ever intended to be run in Python 3.

Comment: @Kevin If you have Python 3 installed then could you test the code and see if that is the case? It doesn't say anywhere in the article that it requires Python 3 so am unsure.

Comment: Does a filename that starts with a non-digit work?

Comment: @EtanReisner Nope changed file name to test.jpg still same error

Comment: Does this run with `-h` (help) argument?  What line does the `syntax error` message cite?

Comment: Do you have this problem if you run the command manually (from a shell) or only through `IDLE`? I just tried the three argparse lines on two different machines (python 2.7.3 and 2.6.9) and those lines worked on both.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought - this may be a clash with IDLE.  Try running from the shell (as you probably have guessed, `python Slic.py --image 0021.jpg`).  Of course, since this is a 5 month old question, I assume that you've resolved it by now :)