# Can't run script with argparse, --datadir error

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to run a script that has argparse implemented. When running it, I get the following error:

> usage: compute_distances.py [-h] --datadir DATADIR --info INFO --outdir OUTDIR
>   compute_distances.py: error: argument --datadir is required

I tried to add a datadir argument, however, I couldn't figure out any way that didn't give me a syntax error afterwards...

//UPDATE2:

Removed all the code that does not immediately belong to the argparse implementation.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main program
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Set up the parsing of command-line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Compute distance functions on vectors")
parser.add_argument("--datadir", required=True, 
                    help="Path to input directory containing the vectorized data")
parser.add_argument("--info", required=True, 
                    help="Name of file containing information about documents (name and label)")
parser.add_argument("--outdir", required=True, 
                    help="Path to the output directory, where the output file will be created")
args = parser.parse_args()

# Read the info file with details of the documents to process
try:
    file_name = "%s/%s" % (args.datadir, args.info)
    f_in = open(file_name, 'r')
except IOError:
    print "Input file %s does not exist" % file_name
    sys.exit(1)

# If the output directory does not exist, then create it
if not os.path.exists(args.outdir):
    os.makedirs(args.outdir)
```

Script call

```
compute_distances.py [-h] "datadir"
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: Without showing your code and based on what you described, the problem could be *anything*. You need to show what you have tried *and* copy exactly the error that you are getting, otherwise it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Also, show how you are trying to call your program.

Comment: updated, thanks for the quick replies

Comment: OK, so now you posted too much code... please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for what is the appropriate amount of code to post.

Comment: Also, if you are actually calling the program as `compute_distances.py [-h] "datadir"`, the issue is that you are not calling your program correctly.  You need `--datadir`, `--info`, and `--outdir` arguments.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I also tried: compute_distances.py [-h]  "someDir", "file_info.txt", "someDir"
Where someDir is the actual directory. I always get the same error with an arrowhead indicating the last of the quotation marks of the first  "someDir" to be the issue

Comment: I think you need to re-read the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) documentation and understand the difference between optional and positional arguments.

Comment: Also, why do you keep adding `[-h]` in your call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the script with:

```
python compute_distances.py -h
```

you'll see the verbose usage instructions set by the `argparse` module in the code example you've provided. This basically prints the help strings from each call to `parser.add_argument(...)`, e.g.:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--datadir",
    required=True, 
    help="Path to input directory containing the vectorized data"
)
```

So your script call needs to look something more like:

```
python compute_distances.py \
    --datadir ./my_files/vectorized_data/ \
    --info ./my_files/names_and_labels.txt \
    --outdir ./my_files/output_data/
```

Note: the `\` above just continues the command over each new-line (so it's more readable for Stack Overflow) - you can write it all together on one line without the `\`.

Comment: 'python compute_distances.py -h' 
gives a syntax error already. The arrowhead is below the last "s" in distances.

Comment: okay, apparently this is a problem with my IDE (PyCharm). When invoking the script from a terminal it runs just fine. Refer to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29214617/syntax-error-when-trying-to-parse-arguments-python-shell).  Thanks @LeoHuckvale